# Razor 2 parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 application, and I would like to pass more than one parameter to a component that I created. Today it is already receiving 1 parameter, but now I need 2 parameters to be passed.

[image: code1]

How can I resolve this?

I tried to pass the values ​​directly, the complete object and even changing the type in the component I was not successful.

Comment: Create a class to hold all the values you need and pass that instead.

Comment: @DavidG I tried that and it didn't work. I made sure to change the type when receiving the parameter and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show how that didn't work? Showing a [mre] would be helpful, including what how you declare the model in your child component.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for the suggestion, I would post the code but I already found a solution.

Comment: @DiegoLobo: **1)** In my opinion, there is no better solution that strongly typed view. This make debugging easier and so on. You can create compound class and extend it when it's necessary.  **2)** The [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) type might be used too in your case.

Comment: @Jackdaw After reviewing your comment, I implemented it in a strongly typed way and it worked. Okay, now I pass an entire object and I just want to validate the situation, but I believe it was valid.

Comment: @Jackdaw I'll post the solution as soon as possible, it looks like I can't answer my own question yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controversial solution was as follows:

1. I created a record for this specific component:

```cs
public record SituacaoFerramentaDto(SituacaoFerramenta Situacao, StatusControle Controle);
```

2. I changed the component to:

```
@model SituacaoFerramentaDto

@switch (Model.Controle)
{
    case StatusControle.Manutencao:
        <label class="badge text-wrap dark-orange">Manutenção</label>
        break;
    case StatusControle.Alocado:
        <label class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">Alocado</label>
        break;
    case StatusControle.Atrasado:
        <label class="badge bg-danger text-wrap">Atrasado</label>
        break;
    case StatusControle.Disponivel:
    case StatusControle.Outros:
        switch (Model.Situacao)
        {
            case SituacaoFerramenta.Disponivel:
                <label class="badge bg-success text-wrap">Disponível</label>
                break;
            case SituacaoFerramenta.Otimo:
                <label class="badge bg-success text-wrap">Disponível</label>
                <label class="badge bg-success text-wrap">Ótimo</label>
                break;
            case SituacaoFerramenta.Bom:
                <label class="badge bg-success text-wrap">Disponível</label>
                <label class="badge bg-primary text-wrap">Bom</label>
                break;
            default:
                <label class="badge bg-secondary text-wrap">Outro</label>
                break;
        }
    default:
        <label class="badge bg-secondary text-wrap">Outro</label>
        break;
}
```

3. The component call looked like this:

```html
<td class="text-white">
   <partial name="Components/situacao-component" 
          model="new SituacaoFerramentaDto(item.Situacao, 
 item.StatusControle)" />
</td>
```

Thanks for the tip @jackdaw

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

First create the component containing the parameters you want.

```
@model Tuple<string, string>

@{
    var text1 = Model.Item1;
    var text2 = Model.Item2;
}
```

Then, go through parameters using a tuple:

```
<partial name="Components/situacao-component" model="new Tuple<string, string>(item.Text1, item.Text2)" />
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Why a Tuple? Tuples hide _context_, the meaning for each data point. It's much harder to debug and maintain a project when you don't know what "Item2" actually represents.

Comment: @gunr2171 He asked for 2 parameters and not an object. I don't know the context and he said in his response that he tried to pass an object and couldn't. I made a different suggestion.

Comment: A Tuple is an object. If the OP can't pass an object, it would be more beneficial to figure out why that's the case.